# LINQ... ignore nulls for dropdown C#

Tags: linq, null

I have a simple linq query that returns a group of customers. A customer is made up of five fields, some of which might be null.

Corporation, Business Unit, Division, Product group, Contact

A customer that is a big company might have values in all five fields (the below is fictional!):

Microsoft - Windows - Developer Group - Start Menu Team - Bob Jones

A smaller customer might be:

Bob's Breakfast Nook - NULL - NULL - NULL - Bob Jones

So I have a dropdown where I want to list all of the customers:

```
        var qryGetClients = from m in db.clients
                            select new
                            {
                                clientid = m.clientID,
                                corpName = m.corpName,
                                buName = m.buName,
                                divName = m.divName,
                                pgName = m.pgName,
                                contactName = m.contactName

                            };



        DDClientList.DataSource = qryGetClients;
        DDClientList.DataTextField = "completeclientname";
        DDClientList.DataValueField = "clientid";
        DDClientList.DataBind();
```

Now I know I can do this in the query to concatenate the fields into one field:

```
    completeclientname= m.corpName + " " + m.buName + " " + m.divName + " " + m.pgName + " " + m.contactName
```

But if one of those fields is null, my dropdown shows a totally null value. (Like, it doesn't "skip" the record, it displays an empty row.

How do I get the dropdown to display the "completeclientname" even if I have null values in one or more of the fields?

Comment: Is it linq-2-Something? In linq-2-objects null fields should not cause null result value, it looks more like a DB logic

Comment: Entity framework... linq to sql?

Comment: I think you'd better do this with Linq-2-objects. Linq-2-Entity probably won't give you any performance benefits since you do not filter anything.

Comment: I do have a where clause in there, but I left it out for simplicity. (It's where isactive = true)

Comment: Then do `AsEnumerable` in my answer after your `where` clause. In that case filtering will be done in database while string concatenation will be done in client

Comment: Amazing. That did it. Thank you so much. This is a great resource!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var fields = new [] { m.corpName, m.buName, m.divName, m.pgName, m.contactName }
                                .Where(s => s != null);
completeclientname = string.Join(" ", fields);
```

In order to switch from Linq-2-entity to Linq-2-objects use `AsEnumerable`:

```
var qryGetClients = db.clients.AsEnumerable()
                              .Select(m => new {
                                                 clientid = m.clientID,
                                                 corpName = m.corpName,
                                                 ...
                                                 completeclientname = ...
                                               })
                              .ToArray();
```

Comment: holy crap that was fast. Thank you so much. OK, I'm an asp.net newbie... where do I put that code? I don't just put it after the query, do I? (As "m" isn't anything that's recognized outside of the query.) Or does what you have there BECOME the query?

Comment: @walstib, feel free to make this into oneliner and put directly into your `new { ... }` clause. Please note that my comment above might affect whether this answer will work for you or not.

Comment: I'm going to have to get schooled on the terminology! How do I know if i'm using Linq2entity vs linq2objects vs linq2sql?

Comment: if you're working with `IEnumerable` (against using `IQueryable`) then you're dealing with linq-2-objects. Otherwise it depends on where did you get your data from. If you got it from Entity Framework then it's a linq-2-Entity, if you got it from linq-2-sql then it linq-2-sql and so on.